# Linux & NFS: Atomic compare-and-exchange of file ownership

Tags: linux, file-permissions, owner

My IT department made an error and  chowned *every* file on the filesystem to `root:OurGroup`. Then their automatic backup (i.e. `.snapshop`) system created a snapshot, so we no longer have a reference of what the permissions were before.

I'm trying to work with them to make a script which will have the set-uid bit set and owned by root that users can call to re-chown files/directories back to them as needed.

I'm anticipating that they won't want a script that'll chown just anything to them, but may instead be willing to create a new user, chown everything to that user, then have a script users can call which will own chown files to them if it's owned by this other user.

However, to avoid race conditions, I want to find a way to chown if-and-only-if the file is owned by this users. There's a race condition here though: if I do this in two separate calls and two users run this script on a file at the same time, it can cause collisions. Instead I'd like to "change owner if the owner is user" in one call, instead of "if owner is user" followed by "change owner"

Is there an atomic compare-and-exchange primitive for file ownership?

Comment: `I'm trying to work with them to make a script which will have the set-uid bit set and owned by root that users can call to re-chown files/directories back to them as needed.` [Not possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364). You could use `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, to avoid race conditions, I want to find a way to chown if-and-only-if the file is owned by this users. There's a race condition here though: if I do this in two separate calls and two users run this script on a file at the same time, it can cause collisions. Instead I'd like to "change owner if the owner is user" in one call, instead of "if owner is user" followed by "change owner"

You seem to imply that once ownership for a file has changed from `root:OurGroup` to something more sane such as `user1:department-name`  a second user should not be able to change ownership again from `user1:department-name` to `user2:some-team`.

That is not really the problem though...

The problem is not two users running the script at the same time or executing `chown` commands shortly after another or concurrently, the problem is much more difficult:
**How are you going to resolve conflicts when multiple users claim ownership of the same file or directory?**

Imagine that the first user that runs your scrip simply selects every file and directory...

Is your problem resolved when all files transition from `root:OurGroup` as the UID:GID to `user1:department-name` and will ownership then have been restored correctly?
And should the subsequent run from user2 that only wants to own `<path>/Department-Name/User1's files/*` be denied?

---

As @Lacek mentioned - your best bet is to use an older backup as the template for the ownership of any files that still exist in the current file system and only focus newly created files that don't exist in the back-up. (First level approach give those files the same owner as the enclosing directory).

The `chmod` as well as the `chown` command support a `--reference` flag.  You can point to an existing file from your back-up location and `chown` will use owner and group of that reference file/directory rather than having to specify OWNER:GROUP values directly, i.e. something on the lines of:

```
cd /old-backup-of-nfs-share/
find . -exec chmod -v --reference='{}' /current-nfs-mount/'{}' \;
```

Comment: I was originally trying to make it so that, if two users do this simultaneously, they end up with at least a consistent set of permissions instead of a scattering of permissions; however, your post made me think about this more and I think the race condition would still occur during the recursive portion of this change, leading to the same contention... So maybe my idea doesn't actually solve anything......

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in shell, but you can emulate it with `flock` (see [this Stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870221/is-there-any-mutex-semaphore-mechanism-in-shell-scripts#10197327))

However, as Sven pointed out, you'll have to use `sudo` for chowning the files, since setuid bits are ignored on scripts.

Also, it may be a better idea to restore an earlier backup, and check the permissions there. It would probably cover most of the files you want to work with, and it seems to be a more accurate way to restore ownership than leaving the guesswork to users.

Comment: I looked at doing exactly that - going through every file and copying the permissions from backups. However, I then discovered that our IT's backup script replaces the old backups on a weekly basis, and that script ran over the weekend - and this problem was caused on Friday; therefore, all the original permissions are lost. (I'm dead serious; it is this depressing)

Comment: The lesson there of course is that a single snapshot is not a proper backup strategy